# Periodically schedule timer task

Tags: java, multithreading

Just to be sure:

```
void java.util.Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period)
```

If my task takes longer then the `period` parameter then the timer doesn't start a new parallel thread, right? It waits until the task has finished and starts right after.

Comment: Uhm, you should really be using a `ScheduledExecutorService`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) :

> Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that
>   is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially. Timer tasks
>   should complete quickly. If a timer task takes excessive time to
>   complete, it "hogs" the timer's task execution thread. This can, in
>   turn, delay the execution of subsequent tasks, which may "bunch up"
>   and execute in rapid succession when (and if) the offending task
>   finally completes.

I suggest you use [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor%28%29) if you expect your tasks may take longer and should be queued.

Answer (score 1):

Two things, first you should really be using ScheduledExecutorService or Schedulers like quartz for scheduling jobs. Regarding your question, period is the time in milli seconds between successive task execution.

Consider an example where you have scheduled a task to start at 10:00 AM with the delay of 10 mins. Let's say if the first execution takes 10 mins to complete i.e., 10:10 AM then the second execution will start at 10:20 AM.